# What's the difference between PC2400T and PC2400 memory?

Tags: memory

I recently got a hynix memory 8GB PC 2400T,I am not sure what's the difference between PC2400T and PC2400 memory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The suffixes refer to the JEDEC DDR4 standard. JEDEC is a sort of trade organization / standards organization.

PC2400T refers to DDR4 running at a 300MHz memory clock with a 14.6 CAS latency and 17-17-17 timings (CL-tRCD-tRP).

PC2400 is simply a non-specified variant of DDR4 with the same memory clock.

Wikipedia has a nice table on their DDR4 page: [Link to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDR4_SDRAM#JEDEC_standard_DDR4_module[58])

Comment: is that means pc2400t same as pc2400?

Comment: It means that they are both DDR4 with the same memory clock. As PC2400 is a label not specified by the JEDEC standards that RAM could have different timings and/or require a different voltage to reach its maximum speeds. Then again, many manufacturers don't use the JEDEC suffixes so it's hard to say. The only way you'd be able to tell is to compare the detailed memory specifications.